# Positioning labels and border of the HTML Form

Tags: html, css, forms, border

I want to do the border of the HTML Radio like this image. Can anyone help me, please?
It's a group of form controls and contains two radio buttons with labels positioned to the right of the radio buttons. And the border is starting in the same line as the label. [Positioning forms like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLSkg.gif)

[image]

I know how to put the border around it.

Comment: You're looking for the `fieldset` html tag [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) for details.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish this is to wrap your radio and labels in its own `div` container and change its `display` property to `inline-block`

```css
.form-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="m">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="f">
      <label for="female">Female</label>
    </div>
    
  </fieldset>
</form>
```